# The same animation on the second object is not working

Tags: html, css

I have a text "Hello" and the other one is "World" which is written on HTML then I added an animation to these two texts on CSS. The first one object which is "Hello" is working but the it seems the other object "World" does not, I really don't know what is the problem behind this. By the way here's the full details:

**HTML**

```
<html>
 <body>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sample.css">
   <div id="first" class="floating">Hello</div>
   <div id="second" class="floating">World</div>
   <p>hhtrhhthtrhhtrhtrhtrhtrhth<br>
   gggregegg5tg5tgrg5trgrghtrhtrhtrhth<br>
   frgfergregegtrghtrhththrth<br>
   rgregergergjertgjoeruiguoerhjguhjeruih<br>
   fuhefuiwhfuihweruifhuhfureheo<br>
   jhfhufiuhufhurhfowfohweof<br>
   hjfyuedfiedf<br>
   fnheuihferifheruhfuergf</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
#first.floating{
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 100%;
    top: 52%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 42.5%;
    right: 0;
    animation-name: floating;
    -webkit-animation-name: floating;

    animation-duration: 1.5s;   
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;

    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes floating {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(0%);  
    }
    50% {
        transform: translateY(8%);  
    }   
    100% {
        transform: translateY(0%);
    }           
}

@-webkit-keyframes floating {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);  
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(8%);  
    }   
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
    }           
}
#second.floating{
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 100%;
    top: 230%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 42.5%;
    right: 0;
    animation-name: floating;
    -webkit-animation-name: floating;

    animation-duration: 1.5s;   
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;

    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes floating {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(0%);  
    }
    50% {
        transform: translateY(8%);  
    }   
    100% {
        transform: translateY(0%);
    }           
}

@-webkit-keyframes floating {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);  
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(8%);  
    }   
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
    }           
}
p {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 100%;
    top: 290%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 42.5%;
    right: 0;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the `bottom: 0;` from `#second.floating` seems to make the animation work with a `top` value of `230%`. It's a really small movement.

```
#second.floating{
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 100%;
    top: 230%;
    left: 42.5%;
    right: 0;
    animation-name: floating;
    -webkit-animation-name: floating;

    animation-duration: 1.5s;   
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;

    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MtR77/4/)

**Updated** with feedback from comments

Comment: But is it possible to make the animation visible with the top of 230%?

Comment: I have a project site for our school and the second object that I've used here as "World" needs to be on 230% because of the design stuff I made. Can we make two div IDs to use one div class so that the code of the same animation that Im gonna use will not be duplicated instead it will be the one that the two div IDs will be used with the maintaining position :-)

Comment: The top of 230% shouldn't be a problem for the animation, if it doesn't work on your page it's probably an other problem. Maybe other CSS is overriding it? You can avoid duplicating code by making a class with the styling in your CSS and applying it to both elements.

Comment: Can you edit the CSS part to make it work? I hope it does not bother you :)

Comment: I've updated the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MtR77/3/ is this what you are looking for? I think because of bottom: 0; in your CSS the movement wasn't visible.

Comment: This is what I am talking about haha, thank you so much! and thanks alot for helping!

Comment: Great to hear this is working for you! Please accept my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You animation is working. The animation is trying to animate the position 8% between its top position and its bottom position. The second floating div has a top position of 230%, so effectively the same as the bottom position, so it has nothing to animate. If you change the top position to less than 100%, then you should see some movement